# I am creating a contact form to put on my personal website but I cannot figure it out

Tags: php, html

I am creating a contact form for my site, I got it to work kind of, I got a email but it was blank. Then I used the array_keys_exist method to show the output message when the "send" button was clicked but then I guess I missed something up because now it does not work at all. I am still a beginner so I am not sure what the issue is, can someone help me please. Thank you.

```php
    <?php


    if (array_key_exists("submit", $_POST)) {

        $firstName = $_POST['firstname'];
        $lastName = $_POST['lastname'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $title = $_POST['subject'];
        $phoneNumber = $_POST['phonenumber'];
        $comment = $_POST['comment'];

        $commentStr = nl2br(htmlentities($comment));

        $to = "example.test@example.com";
        $header = "From: $firstName";
        $sender = $email;
        $subject = $title;
        $submissionTime = date("D M j G:i:s T Y");
        $message = "From: $email
                    Name: $firstName
                    $commentStr
                    $submissionTime";

        $mailSent = mail($to, $header, $sender, $subject, $message);

        if ($mailSent) {
            $outputResponse = "<p class='success'>I have recieved your email I will be in contact soon. Thank you for contacting me.<p>";
        } else {
            $outputResponse = "<p class='error'>Whoops something went wrong on my end, I was not able to recieve your message at this time :(. If you need to contact me my email is alladin.assaf@mavs.uta.edu. Thank you.<p>";
        }

    }
    ?>
```

```html
    <section>
            <div class="form">
                <form action="" method="POST">
                    <div class="input">
                        <label for="employerfirstname">Employer First Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="firstname" id="emplpoyerfirstname">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input">
                        <label for="employerfirstname">Employer Last Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="lastname" id="employerlastname">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input">
                        <label for="employeremail">Employer Email:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="email" id="employeremail">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input">
                        <label for="subject">Subject:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input">
                        <label for="employerphonenumber">Employer Phone Number:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="phonenumber" id="employerphonenumber">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input">
                        <label for="employercomment">Leave a comment:</label>
                        <textarea name="comment" id="employercomment" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
                    <div class="response">
                        <?php echo $outputResponse ?>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: What is the exception you're getting?

Comment: This website is helped to my for including contact form to my website. https://formspree.io/

Comment: If I watch the documentation of the [PHP mail function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php), the function only allow 4 variables like `mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);` and not like in your example `mail($to, $header, $sender, $subject, $message);` Also some validation on the posted varibles wil help to prevent unaxpected errors

Comment: If I were you I should also save the posted data in a database (With prepared statements or PDO) so when the mail didn't send or you don't receive it you always have a place to check the form posts

Comment: If you look at the docs for `mail()` [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php), you see that it does not take a `$sender` variable, however you can add a sender in the (optional) additional headers array which the mail function does allow. I think this is the problem.